# Does Oracle store trailing zeroes for Number data type?

Tags: sql, oracle

When i am storing numeric values in a table and querying that table in SQL Developer, it is not showing trailing zeroes for Number data type.

```
create table decimal_test(decimal_field number(*,10));

insert into decimal_test(decimal_field) values(10);
insert into decimal_test(decimal_field) values(10.11);
insert into decimal_test(decimal_field) values(10.100);
insert into decimal_test(decimal_field) values(10.00);

select * from decimal_test;
```

and the results are

```
10
10.11
10.1
10
```

These values are processed from java code. In this case i am using `BigDecimal` to store the value.

Before saving to DB, if i have `BigDecimal(10.00)`, after saving, the value returned from DB is `BigDecimal(10)`. Equals method in `BigDecimal` fails because the scale is changed.

And i the decimal precision is not constant. User can set BigDecimal(10.00) or BigDecimal`(10.000)` etc. Because of this, value needs to stored in DB as it is.

Is there any way to store the trailing zeros in oracle?

Comment: I used SQL Developer tool to query the data for testing. But we use java oracle jdbc to query the results in actual scenario.

Comment: I don't think you can tell Oracle to store trailing zeros, but you should be able to configure your SQL client (or your application) to format the output with the desired number of decimals.

Comment: number of decimals are not constant. User can set any number of number of decimals. But there is a max limit.

Comment: If those insignificant zeroes are so important for your users: save those numbers as a `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: @suren: you can use that user-defined number of decimals to format the number in your front end.

Comment: If the value is being used top perform a mathematical operation against then a numeric datatype is appropriate and what you have will allow that. Otherwise make it a character field.

Answer (score 7):

The existence of the trailing zeros is a *display* issue, not a storage issue.  The trailing zeros are not significant, and anyway the internal format of the numbers is immaterial as long as the *values* are correct.  There is no value difference between `10` and `10.00000`.

If you need trailing zeros you can always use formatting when converting the values for display.  For example:

```
System.out.printf("%10.4d\n", decimalValue);
```

If the problem is differences in scale, you can ***set*** the scale to the appropriate value before comparing.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to preserve the scale of the numeric input (which **can be significant** - a measure of 10.1 is different from a measure 10.100) store the *scale* in an extra column.

```
create table decimal_test
(decimal_field number(*,10),
 decimal_scale number(*,0)
);
```

Calculate the scale of the input and store it in the new column `decimal_scale`.

Use this value in the output formating.

I'd **not recommend to store the number as a string** - you preserve the scale but loose the number validation and potentially confuse the CBO with wrong estimation caused by the type conversion...

Answer (score 3):

10 and 10.00 are *generally* the same numbers. (It doesn't make a difference if you have to pay 10 $ or 10.00 $ or even 10.0000 $ :-)

If, however, you want to express the precision of the value as in measurements, so 10.00 means you know the number only up to two decimal places, but the real number can be 10.00001 or 10.009 or whatever, then you must additonally store this information. One way to do this would be using a string datatype, but then you'd have to stick to a certain format ('10.00' or say '10,00') and shouldn't use this for calculations in the database.

Another option would be store the number and an additional column for the precision of decimal places, e.g. value = 10 / decimal_places = 2. I would prefer this over storing a string.

Comment: As a counterpoint example to financial amounts: geographic location coordinates quite often have varying precision especially when you must combine datasets. Knowing how precisely a location was recorded definitely matters.