# Oracle truncates all zeros after the decimal point when storing a number

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When I persist a value from a Java class of datatype `BigDecimal` to Oracle in a column with the datatype `Number(23,5)` it truncates all zeros after the decimal point.

For example if the value is `11.500` only `11.5` will be stored in the column.

Is there any way of stopping the zero's from being truncated?

Comment: Does BigDecimal keep the trailing zeros?

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate @MT0. The question isn't whether Oracle does store trailing zeros, but how to avoid it. This is actually a more useful question - the OP knows full well that Oracle doesn't store trailing zeros because they've already tested it.

Comment: @Ben "Is there any way of stopping the zero's from being truncated?" and "Is there any way to store the trailing zeros in oracle?" are the last lines for each question and are effectively the same. Your/Alex Poole's solution and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199862/1509264) to the other question are also the same.

Comment: @AlexPoole - the OP in the linked thread makes an interesting statement. I don't know Java, so I don't know if it is true, but I understand its meaning. He says: *in Java, the comparison `BigDecimal(10) = BigDecimal(10.00)` fails, because the scale is not the same.* If this is true, it is quite interesting (and odd, really). It's as if the scale is part of the data type, or subtype. But in that case the comparison should not return false, it should throw an error, complaining about data type (or subtype) mismatch. That would be a very strong form of data typing.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your number as a number this is impossible.

It is only possible if you store your number as a character, which is not best practice and seems like a contradiction. You may have serious issues if you want to perform mathematical operations on it.

If your number is actually a number then formatting of the number is the job of the code that displays data to the user.

Within Oracle you'd use [`TO_CHAR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions217.htm#SQLRF06130) to do this formatting:

```
SQL> select to_char(11.5, '99.999') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
 11.500
```

This would obviously be different for other languages...

The point about storing a number as a number is that you can take in formats from anywhere and manipulate it as a number. For example we can change the decimal separator by modifying session-level settings without changing the underlying data

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';

Session altered.

SQL> select 11000.5 from dual;

   11000.5
----------
   11000,5
```

If you perform and operations on a number then the maximum number of decimal places are all taken into account for those operations:

```
SQL> select 1 + 1.123 from dual;

   1+1.123
----------
     2.123
```

I would highly recommend storing numbers as numbers. If this is not a number then by all means store it as a character. A phone number is an example of some data that is often mistakenly stored as a number.

There are two other options, however, they mean you don't have a 1-2-1 mapping between your Java `BigDecimal` and the datatype in the database. You'd need a translation layer going in *and* out of the database or you'd have to change your Java code.

They are, however, other methods of storing the data as you wish.

1. It's possible to store the two numbers separately as integers and concatenate them on extract.

   i.e.

   ```
   create table my_table (
       before_decimal integer
     , after_decimal integer
       );
   ```

   You'd also have to concatenate the two together and convert to a number if you wanted to do any mathematical operations:

   ```
   select to_number(before_decimal || '.' || after_decimal) 
     from my_table
   ```
2. As [Alex has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435485/oracle-truncates-all-zeros-after-the-decimal-point-when-storing-a-number/47435554#comment81825753_47435554) you can also store the number of decimal places as a separate column:

   ```
   create table my_table (
       my_number number
     , no_places integer
       );
   ```

   You'd then need to format the number using this query on exit from the database:

   ```
   select to_char(my_number, '99999999999999999999999.' || lpad('9', no_places, '9')
     from my_table
   ```

Comment: this solution works only when you want to show the data in formatted way but my problem is to store the data the way i have provided in java object.when i am using number(23,5) then i must get 3 decimal points even though it is 0.

Comment: Why must you have 3 decimal points for the stored data? Unless this number is actually a character then the 3 decimal points is a formatting issue.

Comment: there is customer requirement that we need to get the data , exactly same as it was input in java object.

Comment: Then you have to store it in a character as I stated at the top and hope you don't have to do any mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Or store the original number of decimal places as a separate column, and then use that for formatting as a string?

Comment: True @Alex I've updated the answer. I think it'd be more painful than storing as an character though.

Comment: That’s not quite what I meant; I was thinking of storing 11.5 as a number (of course), and also storing 3 as the number of digts after the decimal pont. That would only be used to format the actual value as a string.

Comment: Yeah, I misread your comment then read it again and realised that you'd suggested something different. I then edited my answer to include what you said.

Comment: Thanks Alex poole and Ben for your reply.