# When getting data from the cache, zeros are lost

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I have an entity that is stored in the database

```
public class data {
    @Column(name = "id")
    final String id;
    @Column(name = "length")
    final BigDecimal length;
}
```

When you deserialize from the cache and retrieve the data, I lose zeros

Expected:

```
data{id=3, length=6.00}
```

Actual

```
data{id=3, length=6}
```

Comment: Specifying precision limits the maximum number of decimal digits, not the minimum. If you want to display or write in specific format then use `DecimalFormat.format(..)`

Comment: Depending on the cache used it might serialize cached values. The effect you are seeing might stem from that serialization an deserialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Oracle store trailing zeroes for Number data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199210/does-oracle-store-trailing-zeroes-for-number-data-type)

Comment: @LouisJacomet in BD the value is stored correctly. The essence in deserialization when you get then from the cache

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `precision` and `scale` properties of the @Column annotation.

See: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html

Comment: I use it, but apparently, really zeros are lost at deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The database will save the number with the correct precision if your column has enough precision specified. So `decimal(14,4)` will keep up to 4 decimals.

However, it won't remember the original precision. The scale of the decimal. If you really care about it, you need to store that as well. Or store your number as a String.

This question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199210/does-oracle-store-trailing-zeroes-for-number-data-type).

Comment: If you think the question is a duplicate, please vote to close it as such instead of answering